# Excel workbooks produced by POI don't work when linked

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here is what I'm doing :

1. Create a workbook in memory (book = new HSSFWorkbook(), ...)
2. Save it to disk (book.write(...))
3. Open in Excel (ok)
4. Create another workbook in Excel, which links to the first one (=PoiWorkbook?xls!A1)
5. Close Excel

Then everytime I open the second workbook again, all the links are #N/A, unless I also open the POI-generated workbook at the same time.

I never saw this behaviour with standard workbooks created in Excel.
Anyone has seen this and found a workaround ?

Thanks.

Comment: How can you open two workbooks at the same time? Don't you mean opening one after the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be solved by newer version of POI (using 3.6 right now).